# How to display photo into another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to display photo taken by camera into another UIViewController.
I try this code snippet ,but I think I did something wrong because the photo is not showing in the second view:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageToSave = (editedImage!=nil ? editedImage : originalImage);


    // Check if the image was captured from the camera
    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        // Save the image to the camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
    }

    NSString *docspath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filepathJPG = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagefile.jpg"];

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 0.8);
    BOOL result = [data writeToFile:filepathJPG atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Saved to %@? %@", filepathJPG, (result? @"YES": @"NO") );

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    mainViewController *main = [[mainViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
    main.myImag.image = imageToSave;
}
```

**Update:**

I change to use storyboard for the second view:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"idmain"]){
        mainViewController *main = (mainViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        main.myImag.image = imageToSave;
    }
}
```

And in the mainViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSString *docspath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filepathJPG = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagefile.jpg"];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filepathJPG];
    if (img != nil) {
        // assign the image to the imageview,
        myImag.image = img;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Image hasn't been created");
    }
}
```

but when I press choose the second viewcontroller doesn't appear.

Comment: How is svc.myImag set up? It should be an image view that is a subview of one of the views of the 2nd view controller.

Comment: Because you are assigning image to image view before view controller containing it is pushed. Create a UIImage property in mainViewController class and set that property is imageToSave before pushing the view controller and then assign that image to image view

Comment: Pass the UIImage object instead of set from here. You have to set the passed UIImage object on UIImageView in second VC.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving photo in document directory so you have to access them from document directory

try

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagefile.jpg];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

through this code you can get images from document directory.

Answer (score 0):

...assuming that your `imageToSave` UIImage object is valid (in the first place),

instead of
`svc.myImag.image = imageToSave;`
do this

```
svc.currentImage = imageToSave;
//where currentImage is a UIImage synthesized property in mainViewController class
```

---

and then in the `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear` of the mainViewController class,
set `currentImage` onto the`myImag` UIImageView object.

simply:

```
//mainViewController
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    ...
    myImag.image = currentImage;
}
```

---

Reason?? ...
The iOS documentation for a `UIViewController`'s [-initWithNibName:bundle:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW15) method states that:

> …
>   The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller’s view is accessed. If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the `viewDidLoad` method and perform your tasks there. …

---

see similar: 
[UIImageView not displaying image when property is set too early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954434/uiimageview-not-displaying-image-when-property-is-set-too-early)